# How to migrate an Access ADP Application to ACCDB?

Tags: ms-access

One of my applications is an Access ADP Application running on Access 2010/SQL Server 2008. As Microsoft abandoned support for ADPs altogether starting with Office 2013 my client now pushes for a solution to migrate this application.

In this application we use some special techniques to enable certain features, which are:

- Forms bound to disconnected ADO Recordsets
- Forms bound to temporary tables on SQL Server via ADO Recordsets
- Lots of User Defined Functions which are used in Forms' RecordSource SELECT-Statements
- Intensive Use of Transact SQL Features in SELECT-Statements

Our plan ist to migrate this Application to accdb-Format. My first shot was to use a global ADO Connection variable to replace CurrentProject.Connection and set forms' Recordsets manually in Form_Open Event.

Does anyone have already migrated using this approach and can share his experiences/best practices or are there any other approaches I am not aware of (Linked Tables is propablby not working because of our heavy use of TSQL)?

Comment: why would you say linked tables would not work? linked tables are by far the easiest way to handle back-end tables :). Transactions, heavy SQL queries etc can be performed via passthrough query. As for functions, macros, forms they should be fine with accdb. just make sure you have correct references enabled.

Comment: This might be possible. But how about performance? Are linked tables and passthrough queries efficient? I heard that there are performance issues when tables store more than 100k records?

Comment: you can limit the records to be fetched via odbc settings. Pass-through queries are executed on the SQL server not in Access so yes it is efficient. Access 2013 has navigation pane where data is loaded on demand even if you have 100 tabs. with a simple code you can use pass-through queries to return limited rows to enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things.

Go with bound forms to the linked tables. If you have a form bound to a linked table say with 100,000 rows, and you want to pull ONLY one record?

Use the “where” clause to substitute the parameters you had in the past.

Eg:

```
Docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoice",,,"InvoiceNumber = 123"
```

If course, before the above process you could and would perhaps “ask” the user for the invoice number to work on (you had to do this before – right???).

So we get:

```
strInvoiceNum = “some kind of prompt etc for invoice number”

Docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoice",,,"InvoiceNumber = " & strInvoiceNum.
```

So I STRONG suggest you simply use bound forms, and there is zero need and zero benefit by creating a recordset and then binding that recordset to a form (a complete waste of coding time and developer resources that is not required for the migration.

> > •Forms bound to disconnected ADO Recordsets

You REALLY have to determine if you want to do this. You can use views, but a PT query will be read only. You can of course creating reocrdsets like this:

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

 rs.Open ("select * from contacts"), CurrentProject.Connection
```

Note how we used the built in connection. This works because table “contacts” is a plane jane linked table.

So you can still create disconnected recordsets, but it tends to be a lot of extra work, and in the vast majority of cases, you gain nothing except racking up billable hours for no good reason.

If you have a report based on a complex sql query, then simply spool up sql management studio, and cut + paste that t-sql for the report into SSMS, and then save the sql as a view.

You now link to that view. And now simply set the forms data source to that linked view.

And any parameters in that t-sql have to be removed. Now, in place of that query for the report, you used the linked view. In fact if you give the linked view the same name as what the sql query was, then your report should now work as before.

If you need some parameters for the report, then AGAIN use the where clause like this:

```
Docmd.OpenReport "rtpInvoice",acViewPreview,,"InvoiceNum = 123"
```

Again, performance will be great, and only the records that satisfy you’re where clause “criteria” will come down the network pipe.

If for some reason you do have some store-procs for reports that are based on parameters, then simply create a PT query for that report. You can now use this:

```
   With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryRptInvoice")

      .SQL = "exec spProcName " & strInvoiceNum

   End With

   DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice", acViewPreview
```

Note how in ALL OF these examples, we NEVER had to touch or deal with a connection string in code.

Just keep in mind:
A pass-through query is always read only. So you only use PT queries for things like a report, pick lists etc. for display only and reports.

If a form was based on some t-sql with parameters, then a PT query can’t be used (read only results). So in this case, take the t-sql, cut + paste the t-sql into SSMS, and save it as a view. As noted, remove any @parms you have in that t-sql.

Now, with the linked view, you base the form on that linked view. Again, no recordset creating, no messy connection strings, no nothing.

And again, use the “where” clause of the open form to filter.

The number 1 rule here is to use bound forms/reports, and adopt views when required. As noted, reports are also bound and again no recordset creating is required.

And as noted, for reports you can use s-procs, but always use a PT query as per above report example.

So no, it is a myth that linked tables cause a performance problem – they don’t when used correctly, and for your forms to edit data, they are best to simply be bound directly to the linked table or views.